# active dry yeast and rapid rise yeast

Tags: baking, yeast

My recipe calls for 1 packet active dry yeast. All I have is rapid rise instant yeast. How much instant yeast do I use in substitution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're making the dough by hand, you can substitute 1:1, expect the bread to rise a bit faster using rapid rise or instant. If you're using a bread machine, use 25% less (slightly over 1 3/4 tsp to substitute rapid rise or instant for one packet of active dry).

From [King Arthur Flour](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipe/yeast.html):

> One time when you might not want to use instant and active dry yeasts interchangeably is when you're baking bread in a bread machine. Since bread machines use a higher temperature to raise dough, substituting instant for active dry yeast 1:1 may cause bread to over-rise, then collapse. When baking in the bread machine, and substituting instant yeast for active dry, reduce the amount of instant yeast by 25%.

Comment: Good point about making bread in a bread machine, even though I'd never do that, because all the joy lies in kneading the dough by hand!